# Deleting from USB drive while using enterprise network (windows 7)

Tags: windows-7

I'm curious about something which, apologies, is hard to succinctly say in the subject line. In any case, here's what I've done (and has me worried as an employee for lack of caring on my own part).

We have a large network (30k users), primarily running Windows 7... profiles are shared/roaming (I guess?) so you can sign into any machine and have a profile generate for you for use. I recently plugged in a USB drive of mine (at the office), then deleted some no-no videos (ahem) directly from the drive (Shift + delete to permanently delete in Windows), if I call correctly.

Is there any kind of logging of the media itself, despite being deleted, on the network?

Two scenarios:

- If I actually did a shift+delete, should I be worried?
- If I deleted to recycle bin, then delete from there (emptying the bin), should I be worried?

It feels like on the latter option, if a sysadmin were to investigate, they might see filenames, sizes, meta info stuff... is that the case (since the file was delete from the USB drive and moved into the profiles recycle bin). Or is it just a pointer to that file on the USB drive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without knowing the technologies at play, there is no way to answer this question on its face.

There are several kinds of technology in particular that might cause you issues, including ambient versioning systems like [Microsoft Volume Shadow Services](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc785914%28v=ws.10%29.aspx). Luckily VSS isn't likely to be a problem unless it was configured to operate on the USB disk. If it is owned by the company however, plug it in, and check the Propreties on a recently changed file. Is there a "Previous Versions" tab, and does it show any prior versions of the file? if so, VSS has been enabled.

Data Exfiltration systems are a bigger concern, as they do concern themselves with USB disks, and are designed to distrust the operator. Check our this whitepaper on how an organization might use USB auditing to prevent data exfiltration incidents on the Microsoft platform: http://resources.sei.cmu.edu/library/asset-view.cfm?assetID=35427.